# Why is WolframAlpha and WolframAlpha Widgets Giving me Different Answers?

Tags: partial-derivative, wolfram-alpha, online-resources

I was just wondering in anyone's experience, if they came across an official WolframAlpha Calculation (using https://www.wolframalpha.com/) that was different from one of the widgets (which I think is unofficial and community made, for example, [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/gallery/view.jsp?id=35764b7940c52f2ba9a2f2586c094ee6)).

The issue is, I don't understand if they are actually giving me different answers (thus causing me to cast doubt on ever using WolframAlpha Widgets again unless I am completely wrong on this).

- **WolframAlpha [Official](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)**

[image: Wolfram Alpha Official]

- **[WolframAlpha Widget](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/gallery/view.jsp?id=35764b7940c52f2ba9a2f2586c094ee6)**

[image: Wolfram Alpha Widget]

**If they aren't could someone tell me if these expressions are mathematically equivalent?**

Comment: I imagine, from the widget, write as a single fraction, factor $x^{\rho-2}(x^\rho+y^\rho)^{(2-\rho)/(\rho-1)}$ from the numerator, and simplify the other factor.

Comment: Hi David, I'll give that I go and let you know if that works! Thank you.

Comment: I've edited your post to include your screenshots to this post.  Using images here is fine, as you want to show us the output of the aforementioned web services.  That qualifies as images which provide illustration.  However, I downvoted due to the lack of context for the visually impaired.  The context is fine for those who can see, but the visually impaired don't know that you're using $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( x^{\rho - 1} \sqrt[\rho - 1]{x^\rho + y^\rho} \right)$ as an example.  Until you edited your post to include that in your question body, $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two answers are identical.

Wolfram Alpha uses Wolfram Language as the underlying syntax. The correct expression in Wolfram Language would be

```
D[x^(rho-1) * (x^rho+y^rho)^(1/(rho-1)), x]
```

leading to the same answer as in the widget.

My guess of why you are getting the same answer expressed differently is because there is ambiguity in your Wolfram Alpha Official input. In the input

```
derivative (x^(rho-1))*((x^rho+y^rho))^((1/(rho - 1)))
```

WAO doesn't immediately know if what you want is

```
(derivative (x^(rho-1)) w.r.t. x) * ((x^rho+y^rho))^((1/(rho - 1)))
```

or

```
derivative ((x^(rho-1)) * ((x^rho+y^rho))^((1/(rho - 1)))) w.r.t. x
```

or one of the two above inputs, but with respect to y or to rho. Therefore it has to guess what is the most likely thing that you want - presumably this involves some internal rearrangements of the input, and once WAO figures out what it is that you most likely want, it performs the derivative with respect to the input that WAO thinks is correct.

If you clarify your intent by enclosing the expression in brackets and specifying the variable with respect to which the derivative should be computed, e.g.

```
derivative ((x^(rho-1))*((x^rho+y^rho))^((1/(rho - 1)))) wrt x
```

the output will be identical to that of the widget.

Note that the widget doesn't have these ambiguities because from f(x,y)=expression it knows what the variables are (because they're specified in f(x,y)), and it knows what the intended expression is.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the detailed explanation Randy! It is much appreciated.

Comment: I just wanted to ask for the future, do wolframalphawidgets basically work the same as the official wolframalpha calculator? Or should I always be cautious when using one of them? (Sorry for asking wolframalpha questions here; I posted a thread on their forums about this but no-one has answered yet).

Comment: I do not know how widgets work, I have never used one, presumably it is the same engine as Wolfram Alpha. In my opinion learning Wolfram Language syntax (through e.g. Wolfram Mathematica if you can afford a licence) would remove the need for caution when working with WA in most cases. If you can't afford the licence, the syntax can be learned with the help of Mathematica's online documentation.

Comment: I understand, thank you @randy